# Discordjs, How to not use cooldown when the command isn't properly executed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I use wokcommands for easy command and event handling. There's a built in command cooldown. I wanna know how to except an error to it's cooldown. Like if the command isn't executed properly the cooldown wont work or will reset.